# Repeated error when adding packages

Tags: openbsd

Is there anyone actively monitoring OpenBSD questions here? I am trying to install `nano` and then `xfce4` and then a few other programs, but every time I try to use `pkg_add`, I get the message:

> Fatal error: bad list v: No such file or directory at
>   /usr/libdata/per15/OpenBSD/Pkg_Add.pm line 1115

I have been reading the man pages, but there is very little help when Googling.

It was a new install of OpenBSD on an old i386 laptop. I used the `install56.iso` install image. Then I tried installing several programs from OpenBsd packages using another CD, USB and then trying to download them onto the computer. I got the same error message every time. The command has never worked. This is my first attempt to get an OpenBSD system running.

Comment: Please provide more context.  As is stands, your question is inanswerable.  Is this a new install?  Has pkg_add -ever- worked on this machine?  You seem inexperienced:  How exactly did you install?  Any ‘interesting’ configuration going on?  Explain us what you’ve done so far, then we might be able to figure out what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share what I posted in [this request](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179480/what-bad-list-v-no-such-file-or-directory-at-usr-libdata-per15-openbsd-pkg-a/187499#187499)

> I had run into the same issue while following blogged instructions. It
>   turned out, the command I was using was incorrectly formatted. My
>   mistake, `pkg_add -lv software` the tags after `-` should have been an
>   uppercase `I` and a lower case `v` instead of a lowercase `L` and a
>   lowercase `v`. This occurred through a misinterpretation with the
>   fonts used on the instructions used.
>
> `pkg_add -Iv software`
>
> After correcting this typo, everything went well. Hopefully, this also
>   corrects your issue and good luck.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).